# I keep getting unitialized variable used for interestRate, numberOfPayments, and loanAmount

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration, undefined-behavior

Sarah Connors is fName and lName, 10000 is loanAmount 12 interestRate and 3 is the number of years for the loan, this is all located in "Lab4Data.txt"

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fName, lName;
    
    double interestRate, loanAmount, monthlyPayment, totalPayed, interestAmount,

    double numberOfPayments

    ifstream input;

    ofstream output;
    
    input.open("Lab4Data.txt");
    output.open("Kirklandlab4results.txt");
    interestRate = interestRate / 12;
    interestRate = interestRate / 100;
    numberOfPayments = numberOfPayments * 12;
    
    monthlyPayment = loanAmount * interestRate
            * pow(loanAmount + interestRate, numberOfPayments)
            / pow(loanAmount + interestRate, numberOfPayments) - 1; //equation to get monthly payment
    totalPayed = monthlyPayment * numberOfPayments;
    interestAmount = interestRate * numberOfPayments;
    
    input >> fName >> lName;
    output << "Name:" << fName << " " << lName;
    
    input >> loanAmount;
    output << "Loan Amount:" << loanAmount << endl;
    
    input >> interestRate;
    output << "Monthly Intrest Rate:" << interestRate << endl;
    
    input >> numberOfPayments;
    output << "Number Of Payments:" << numberOfPayments << endl;
    
    output << "Monthly Payment:" << monthlyPayment << endl;
    output << "Total Amount Payed:" << totalPayed << endl;
    output << "Interest Amount:" << interestAmount << endl;
    
    output.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

im trying to figure out why its telling me that im getting unitialized variable used for interestRate, numberOfPayments, and loanAmount. I am new to C++ and need help.

Comment: You execute this: `interestRate = interestRate / 12;`  before you read the value of `interestRate`. Note that in c++ these are value assignments not formulas that are executed every time you look at a variable.

Comment: C++ isn't a spreadsheet. Computations are not updated after a variable involved in the computation is changed. If a variable changes and you need the new result, you have to run the computation again. If you run the computation BEFORE the variable gets a value, you wind up with an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 1):

In these statements

```
interestRate = interestRate/12;
interestRate = interestRate / 100;
numberOfPayments = numberOfPayments * 12;
monthlyPayment = loanAmount * interestRate;
```

there are used uninitialized variables

```
double interestRate, loanAmount, monthlyPayment, totalPayed, interestAmount, 
    
double numberOfPayments;
```

that invokes undefined behavior.

For example what is the value of the variable `interestRate` in this expression `interestRate/12`? As the variable was not initialized (neither value was assigned to it in its declaration) it contains some garbage.

Comment: I have no idea what uninitialized variables that invokes undefined behavior, if you could explain to me more thoroughly if possible as I am new to c++.

Comment: @kirqy See the question in my answer.

Comment: interest rate is 12 which is written in the text file "Lab4Data.txt" it reads                  
 Sarah Connors 10000 12 3  //Sarah Connors is fName,Lname 10000 is LoanAmount, 12 is interestRate and 3 is numberOfPayments// numberOfPayments I believe is defined but im a little iffy about using that variable how I did.

Comment: @kirqy Reread my answer one more. What is unclear?

Comment: @kirqy The program read the data from the file AFTER it computes `interestRate = interestRate/12;` At the time of the computation, `interestRate ` has no known value. What is the value of `y` in `y = x+1` if you do not know the value of x?

Comment: So would I have to declare another variable for x? @user4581301

Comment: @kirqy You have tp assign a value to the variable before using it. What is unclear?